# does jquery html result replace targeted div or append content

Tags: javascript, jquery

From javascript function on success action I'm injecting content to div using it's id.

```
$.ajax({
             url: formatUrl('/MyController/MyActionMethod'),
             type: 'POST',
             contentType: 'application/json',
             data: JSON.stringify({ id: target }),
             success: function (result) {   
                   $("#myPopUp").html(result); 
                   $("#myPopUp").popup("open");
             },
             error:...
        });
```

on Layout.cshtml view page I have div

```
<div id="myPopUp" data-role="popup">
      <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>        
    </div>
```

Popup renders content fine, but without close button on popup window.

My question is: If I send result to the #myPopUp from javascript do I overwrite `<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>` content since it is under  `<div id="myPopUp" .. />` tag.

Comment: Yes you will overwrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.html() is going to overwrite the < a > dom element.

.append() will add it to #myPopUp so that it is a sibling of the < a > element.